# Is it possible to do cohesion block in parallel with igraph?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, igraph

I have a network of about 2k nodes and 4.8k edges which exhibits high small world attributes. I want to get its cohesion blocks with `cohesive.blocks()` in `igraph`, however, it has been running for days and still not output.

There was a link similar with this issue (https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2008-01/msg00020.html), and `MPI` was mentioned to run `cohesive.blocks()` in parallel. So I wonder how to run `cohesive.blocks()` or other functions in `igraph` in parallel.

Thanks.

Comment: Also take a look at this thread on the igraph mailing list: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2009-09/msg00045.html